# What culture (or cultures) did the Albino recruit his troops from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

On the Memory Alpha page for the *DS9* episode ["Blood Oath"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Blood_Oath_(episode)), the Albino's second-in-command is identified as a [Markalian](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Markalian).  However, the rank and file are shown with one-way visors that cover their faces and so we never see what species they hail from (or if they even all come from the same species).

Are his guards Klingon, Markalian or another race?

Answer (score 4):

Given the Albino's evident disdain for Klingons (he refers to them as "*filth*") it's pretty reasonable to assume his guards aren't Klingon warriors but there's no indication what race they do come from.

Based on what we see in the episode, at least one of the guards appear to be human but that's only because you can't see his [rubber forehead](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubberForeheadAliens).

[image]

The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/439.txt) simply refers to them as "non-descript guards".

> Non-Speaking : N.D. GUARDS